# Continuous integration of HTML frontend with Spring MVC backend developed by 2 different teams

Tags: web-applications, spring-mvc, continuous-integration

What is the best way to continuously integrate 2 parallel processes:

- Developing static HTML frontend by designers team
- Developing Java Spring MVC backend by backend team

The questions are:

- How could the designers do their work, without running a local Tomcat to test
  their UI updates with jsp includes OR
- How could the backend team get updates from the UI team, without making updates
  in JSP pages by hand for every UI update
- Is it possible to make projects in 2 different git repositories (one for
  frontend and one for the backend) and build a full solution with Jenkins
- What are best practices to devide UI (HTML) from the backend (Spring MVC)
  with minimal work for integration (best if it is auto integration with Jenkins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The division of work into two teams (designer and backend) does not currently reflect the division of the software into two components. This means that both teams are too influenced by each other's work. I can see three ways to go about this.

**Adapting the application architecture to match the teams**

You could try and change the architecture of your application, splitting it into two components more aligned with the two teams. This is where you're heading, from the sound of your questions.

This is most succesful for the development of MVVM applications. In the .Net world, designers create Views using XAML markup language and the Expression Blend tool and the developers create the Models ViewModels that bind to the XAML view. Same for knockout.js MVVM applications.

JSPs are not fit for this purpose, but using [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/) sounds extremely attractive to me if you are heading this way. Its templates are valid xhtml pages. Or maybe you can put a REST interface on the web server, move the binding of objects to javascript and do MVVM using knockout.js.

**Adapting the teams to match the application architecture**

You could change the composition of the teams. Merge them into one team or if that's too many people, create two teams consisting of both designers and backend developers and have them work on different feature sets. This way you can achieve more interaction between the developers and designers. Have more moments where a developer and a designer sit behind one screen together making changes to the JSPs. Have developer and designer discuss the changes for each feature and figure out a handy way to divide those changes on a feature by feature basis.

**Keep both teams and architecture as they are, formalize the handover**
Let the designers produce HTML + CSS and let the developers incorporate these artifacts into the code. A nice and clean cutoff point that requires little change to the teams and the software.

Comment: Added a link to Thymeleaf which sounds like a very good way to split the application into designer and backend components.

Answer (score 1):

I have a proposal :

Steps to achieve parallel work and minimal work when integration:-

1.) Define all UI mockup's, functionality and dataModel return from controller.

2.) Build Single Page Application(SPA)

3.) Use Ajax call from UI to Interact with controller.

4.) Use jsonView in controller to return values as Json Object.

5.) Use jetty server(Proxy) for UI team to return dummy response as controller returns, so that they can create UI based on mockup and dataModel.

6.)Back-end Team can develop their code from controller with the use dataModel and functionality defined before in any server.Since controller return json response they can check the return value in the browser itself as json string.

So Finally whenever you need to integrate just make proxy as false in ui server.

Its the way that we worked on X project .